# How can I ensure that I only insert one row theese specific characteristics attributes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, foreign-keys, unique

In the following database layout:

- there can be multiple courses for the same topic
- A student can be in multiple courses

I want to ensure that a student is only in one course for the same subject.

I don't want to ensure 100% consistency, I am worried about concurrency issues.

This means I am fine with a table/row locking solution and don’t require a trigger that simulates a unique key constraint.

[image: db diagram]

Of course I could add the subject_id to the relation and make a unique key, but then I would store it redundantly which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question correctly, but if I do, this is my answer:

Remove the `id` column from `student_course_relation` and put the `primary key` on `id_student` and `id_course`.

This way, only the combination of those needs to be unique.

Comment: No, that would mean a student can only be in one course. A student can be in several courses, but only in one course of the same subject! Of course I could add the topic id to the relation and make a unique key, but then I would store it redundantly which I dont want.

Comment: Do you mean `topic` instead of `subject` ?

Comment: Yes, i do. Sorry. @DavidK-J

Comment: People need to stop using id for everything and start modelling data correctly, because I don't get where you'd like to go with this....
Anyhow, It might be better to use a stored procedure to add the students to a course.
That way, you can check IN the stored procedure if a student is already in a course with the same topic, use Transaction management to do it all correctly and rollback it all when it's now allowed to do so.

And I really recommend to delete the id in the student_course_relation table

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that a promising solution for my problem is to use the `GET_LOCK()` function in MySql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

to get a lock on a student id specific name in the conneciton, then select the course, do the insert.
A second connection will have to wait for the same lock and then the select of the course id will return the id.